# Smallest circuit for Ultrasonic Mist Maker or humidifier

Tags: high-frequency, resonance, ultrasound, low-voltage, humidity

I am working on Ultrasonic Mist Maker or humidifier circuit, but does not found any good circuit.

As search on google that we have to make about frequency 1.6MHz to convert water into mist. using these type of piezoelectric transducer

[image]

i found some circuits like this one
[image]

But its very big circuit with many components used.
We require small size circuit with lowest possible components used.

Comment: Why do you need to minimize the number of components you use? That circuit only has a few dozen, anyway, which seems like not very many to me.

Comment: The left part of the circuit is the mains supply. Replace it with a battery and you got rid of it. The middle part of the circuit is a water detector. Simply remove it if you don't need that function. The remainder is one transistor, one diode, three caps and three coils, which aren't removeable.

Comment: you can't get much simpler than this

Comment: You can be very sure that those consumer electronics designs have cost pared down low. You can relax the requirements, as Janka suggests or perhaps there is some ridiculously expensive one-chip solution from a boutique IC house that saves  a part or two compared to the super-cheap one-transistor self-resonant oscillator circuit shown. For example the Chinese novelty fountains run from low voltage 24VDC so the power supply complexity is externalized.

Comment: That's probably a 30 year old design judging by its componentry. Nowadays you can probably repurpose a switch mode convertor IC like a boost convertor, just look for one that switches at about 1.6MHz.

Comment: The series resonator of L3 and C3 do not resonate at 1.6MHz.

Comment: The smallest circuit would be a few square mm's on an IC, if you can afford an asic. Please rephrase your question.