# How can I change a DC current to a 1.7/2.4 MHz AC current for piezoelectric device

Tags: frequency, inverter, converter, piezoelectricity

I would like to start by saying my experience in electronics is very limited and I will include pictures of everything. I am, however, trying to assemble a device which puts a current through a piezoelectric transducer to resonate at ultrasonic frequencies and atomize liquid water (hopefully).

I have found two cheap "humidifiers" on eBay with high resonance frequencies (1.7/2.4 MHz) and low current requirements. The power source I would like to use is a 3.6 V/15 A battery. My understanding is the piezo-transducer will resonate according to the frequency of its AC current.

Battery:

[image: Battery]

Question:

My question is: What is the most cost-effective method to convert my DC battery to AC with the frequency of 1.7 MHz & 2.4 MHz (these will be separate circuits)? Is there something I can use as an inverter but with variable frequencies, and would it matter if the waveform was square or sine?

Also, I think I will probably want to step-up the voltage, but I don't know how that would factor in here.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I've removed images of the previous transducers as they are lacking specifications. Below are links to a transducer and spec sheet which seems to be better quality. This transducer runs on 1.65 MHz and it is different from those previously posted, so please be sure to take a glance at that spec sheet. As far as power, I have had trouble figuring out how volts/amps/watts relate to the rate the water atomizes at. I assume I would adjust the amps and keep the volts consistent to adjust this factor?

Also just to add to my question, I need to prove this is all done in compact, energy efficient, and relatively cost efficient manner because this design would need to be reproducible on a larger scale. It may be the kind of thing where I actually have to test it out to narrow down the right amp/voltage, but for now let's just assume the power is the max 30 Watts.

**1.65 MHz Transducer:** [Product Page](https://www.newark.com/prowave/m165d25/ultrasonic-sensors/dp/97K6189)  [Spec Sheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/81205.pdf)

Comment: Discussed in this hobbyist video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKhPj7uFD0Y

Comment: [Here is a similar question.  It includes a complete driver circuit.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374212/smallest-circuit-for-ultrasonic-mist-maker-or-humidifier)

Comment: In the circuit that JRE refers to the actual piezo driver is the componentry  including and to the right of C3 L3. As noted there - that is a very old circuit and there will be better ways- but it shows you one method.

Comment: Can you supply a link to a "real" data sheet - and the source of what you have rather than a picture. What power level is required to achieve the throughput you want. If you do not know you need to find out. We could reserach this but ideally byou will provide the information. | Is this a one off / few / many task.

Comment: Numerous circuits [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=ultrasonic+piezo+driver&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjeh4vTucXhAhWuHjQIHbJSCWkQsAR6BAgmEAE&biw=1152&bih=566&dpr=1.25) using Google image search.

Comment: You definitely do not want a variable frequency motor drive (VFD). I will remove that tag.

Comment: glanced through the circuit diagrams provided, edited my initial post. Would any of you suggest a specific circuit based on the additional information? Thank you so much.